# Envío de archivo de texto desde Android

Tags: java, android, linux, windows

Que tal amigos, estoy desarrollando una aplicación que genera un archivo de texto (`.txt`) con múltiples líneas obtenidas de una BD, para luego enviar a través de un correo, el problema es cuando se recibe el correo y al ver el archivo en una PC, el texto sale en una sola línea, al ver el mismo archivo en el celular si tiene el salto de línea.

Este es el código que uso para concatenar y guardar en un archivo de texto:

```
BufferedWriter fileWritter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/arhivos/"+currentDate)); //ubicacion y nombre del archivo
while(c.moveToNext()){                               
  registros = String.format(codigoReloj + c.getString(0).toString() + c.getString(1).toString().replace("/", "") + c.getString(2).toString().replace(":", "")+"\n");
  fileWritter.append( registros );
  fileWritter.flush();
  registros = "";
}
fileWritter.close();
```

Este es el código que uso para enviar el archivo

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);         
     emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
     emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, asunto);
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mensaje);
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+"/storage/sdcard0/archivos/"+ asunto)); 
     emailIntent.setType("text/plain"); //indicamos el tipo de dato      
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email "));
```

Ya intenté generar el archivo con:

```
writer.newLine();
System.getProperty("line.separator");
String.format("%n");
```

Con estas opciones en el celular se visualiza los saltos de líneas, luego de enviarlo y ver el archivo en una PC, el texto sale en una sola línea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este parece ser un problema relacionado con la diferente representación del carácter de **nueva línea**, dependiente del sistema operativo. De acuerdo con [*Nueva línea - Wikipedia*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nueva_l%C3%ADnea#Problemas_comunes) (énfasis agregado):

> <sup>Las diferentes representaciones de la *nueva línea* en los sistemas operativos a veces causan que al transferir un fichero entre dos ordenadores, se muestre incorrectamente. **Por ejemplo, en condiciones normales, los ficheros creados en sistemas Unix o Apple Macintosh se verán como una línea larga en Windows.** Y a la inversa: los ficheros creados en un ordenador con Windows se verán extraños con algunos editores, ya que el CR extra que Unix no necesita se mostrará como un ^M al final de cada línea.</sup>

Típicamente el carácter de **nueva línea** se representa como:

- `\n` = `LF` (*Salto de línea*) Usado como carácter de nueva línea en Unix.
- `\r` = `CR` (*Retorno de carro*) Usado como carácter de nueva línea en Mac OS.
- `\r\n` = `LF` `CR` Usado como carácter de nueva línea en Windows y MS-DOS.

Cuando mencionas:

> Con estas opciones en el celular se visualiza los saltos de lineas, luego de enviarlo y ver el archivo en una PC, el texto sale en una sola línea.

Entonces, asumiendo que por PC te refieres a una computadora con Windows, el carácter de nueva línea que debes usar es `\r\n`. En otras palabras:*

```java
fileWritter.append(registros)
           .append("\r\n");
```

<sub>────────

* En este pequeño ejemplo, `registros` no debe contener `\r` o `\n`. Se recomienda agregar el carácter de nueva línea en una llamada independiente a `.append`. Adicionalmente, también se recomienda, para mejorar el rendimiento, hacer `flush` justo antes de cerrar la instancia de [`Writer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Writer.html).</sub>

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, habia visto ese código, pero lo estaba aplicando mal, dejo lo que me funcionó.

`
BufferedWriter fileWritter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/archivos/"+currentDate));       
    
while(c.moveToNext()){
     
registros = codigoReloj + c.getString(0).toString() + c.getString(1).toString().replace("/", "") + c.getString(2).toString().replace(":", "");
     
fileWritter.append( registros ).append("\r\n");
     
registros = "";
     
}

fileWritter.flush();
fileWritter.close();
`

Answer (score 0):

Usted puede tratar de usar o emplear algo similar a lo siguiente quizas sea lo que busca:

```
//..

String message = "Hola esto es<br/><br/>un test";

..//
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mensaje);
..//
```

.

```
//..

..//
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                     Html.fromHtml("Hola esto es<br/><br/>un test"));
..//
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es que **siempre guardes en el formato de salto de línea de Windows** ya que **de Windows a linux es compatible**, pero no es así si lo guardas en formato Linux.

Con ello evitarás ir de una transformación de datos a otra, simplemente guarda siempre en formato Windows.

De todas formas **con este código puedes convertir Lineas de Linux a Lineas de Windows**

```
public class LineConverter{

    //convierte a formato de línea de UNIX
    static String convertToUNIXNewlines(String value) 
    {
       return value.replace("\r\n", "\n");
    }


    //convierte a formato de línea de Windows
    static String convertToWindowsNewlines(String value)  
    {

      //llama al de UNIX para asegurarse de tener siempre 
      //el mismo formato
      value = convertToUNIXNewlines(value);
      return value.replace("\n", "\r\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      String value = "Juan\nCarlos\nRuiz\r\nPacheco";
      String result = LineConverter.convertToWindowsNewlines(value);

      System.out.println(value);
      System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
Juan
Carlos
Ruiz
Pacheco
Juan
Carlos
Ruiz
Pacheco
```

#### Puedes probarlo en línea [aquí](http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/411728)

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas agregar saltos de linea en el texto de tu email en el caso de Android (ya que veo usas un Intent), se usa regularmente el tag html `line break <br>` que produce un salto de línea y retorno de carro (carriage-return). En lugar de `\n` usa `<br>`, el cual también puedes agregar al final de cada línea, agregalo al realizar la llamada a .append() :

```
BufferedWriter fileWritter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/arhivos/"+currentDate)); //ubicacion y nombre del archivo
while(c.moveToNext()){                               
  registros = String.format(codigoReloj + c.getString(0).toString() + c.getString(1).toString().replace("/", "") + c.getString(2).toString().replace(":", "")+"<br>");
  fileWritter.append(registros + "<br>");
  fileWritter.flush();
  registros = "";
}
fileWritter.close();
```

Así al enviar el email :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);         
     emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
     emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, asunto);
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mensaje);
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+"/storage/sdcard0/archivos/"+ asunto)); 
     emailIntent.setType("text/plain"); //indicamos el tipo de dato      
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email "));
```

y recibirlo en el cliente, tu mensaje se formara con saltos de linea y no en una sola línea, esta imagen muestra como se vería el texto en un dispositivo móvil o en una pc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### *** Es importante hacer saber que algunos Clientes de email filtran el contenido html.**